# Creating folders on the BeagleBone Black in Python

Tags: python-2.7, usb, directory, beagleboneblack, mmc

I have code in Pyhton(2.7) on a beagle bone black to create folders that I copy fills of data to.  These folders are mounted to the micro-Sd card(archive) and a thumb drive(live data copy). The file is being made in my working dir.

Code:

```
@staticmethod  # Creates a folder if not present
def create_folder(folder_name):
    directory = os.path.dirname(folder_name)
    try:
        os.path.exists(directory)
        print("Folder failed")
    except:
        os.makedirs(directory, 0o777)
        print("Folder created")
```

Error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/TEMS_Operations/System_Files.py", line 125, in <module>
    temp.create_folder(temp.main_folder)
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/TEMS_Operations/System_Files.py", line 41, in create_folder
    directory = os.path.dirname(folder_name)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 122, in dirname
    i = p.rfind('/') + 1
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rfind'
```

Any Suggestions?

Test program:

```
def test(self):                 # System file test
    name1 = self.alarm_file()
    print(name1)
    name2 = self.data_file()
    print(name2)
    name3 = self.main_folder()
    print(name3)
    name4 = self.arch_folder()
    print(name4)

    self.create_data_file(name2)
    self.create_alarm_file(name1)
    self.create_folder(name3)
    self.create_folder(name4)

    file_to = name3 + name1
    file_from = mane4 +name1

    self.copyfile(file_from, file_to)


temp = SystemFiles("ZapOFS", "ZapLab")
print(os.getcwd())
temp.test()
```

Errors:

```
    /media/mmc/2019/1
    /media/usb/2019/1
    File created
    File created
    <type 'str'>
    Folder failed
    <type 'str'>
    Folder failed
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ikpdb.py", line 1866, in main
    ikpdb._runscript(mainpyfile)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ikpdb.py", line 1415, in _runscript
    exec(statement, globals, locals)
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/TEMS_Operations/System_Files.py", line 132, in <module>
    temp.test()
  File "/var/lib/cloud9/TEMS_Operations/System_Files.py", line 127, in test
    copyfile(file_from, file_to)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/shutil.py", line 82, in copyfile
    with open(src, 'rb') as fsrc:
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/usb/2019/1ZapOFS_ZapLab_Alarm_File_2019_1.csv'
[IKPdb-g] 16:34:52,604104 - INFO - Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging
```

Comment: What are you passing in create_folder method?

Comment: I am sending the string for the destination. "/media/usb/archive/date"

Comment: Can you try adding `print type(folder_name)` after this `def create_folder(folder_name):` line and check what is the type of the `folder_name`

Comment: See above for information

Comment: Please add this code snippet as well
File "/var/lib/cloud9/TEMS_Operations/System_Files.py", line 125, in <module>
    temp.create_folder(temp.main_folder)

Comment: error: 
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'rfind'
[IKPdb-g] 22:09:18,071892 - INFO - Uncaught exception. Entering post mortem debugging

Comment: Now you are getting different exception `NameError: global name 'mane4' is not defined`

Comment: Typo that was corrected: nane for name

Comment: `IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/media/usb/2019/1ZapOFS_ZapLab_Alarm_File_2019_1.csv` 
this error is self-explanatory.

Comment: The main issue here is that It will not allow for me to transfer files to a folder. This folder was attempted to be created in my python program before the file transfer. I have ensured that the folders contain the proper -rw permissions and have even changed the folder owner. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to allow the creation of folders in python on the mounted MMC and/or USB drives on the BeagleBone black is to remove the sudo password for the current users and add -rw permissions for the program.

```
# sudo echo "debian  ALL=NOPASSWD: ALL" >>/etc/sudoers
```

Not what I was hoping for, but the only way i can find.

https://elinux.org/Beagleboard:BeagleBoneBlack_Debian